What is the correct strategy for indexing a postgres database for filtering
I want to create indexes in my postgres DB which contains a massive amount of data. The Usecase is to have a frontend, which should be able to filter a few selected fields and in the backend based on the selected filters the query should be built.
The possible fields, which can be filtered are: vu, tid, date, amount, status, type, source, brand, group (all fields are varchar, date is a dateTime)
vu, tid and date are always present in every query. A query can look like this:
explain analyze
SELECT 
    id,
    type ,
    amount ,
    currency,
    tid,
    vu,
    group,
    brand ,
    reference,
    receipt,
    date,
    status 
FROM tablename
WHERE vu IN ('123456') 
  AND tid IN ('123','456') 
  AND date BETWEEN '2024-10-07T00:05:10.213Z' AND '2024-12-10T14:00:00.000Z'
  AND type = 'TESTVALUE'
LIMIT 25;

The thing is all other fields can also be present in the query, if selected in the filter.
I tried to create a filter which handles the vu, tid, and date as well as amount, bc this is a common filter which is also often added:
CREATE INDEX idx_vu_tid_date_amount ON tablename (vu, tid, date, amount)

If no filters are set or only amount this obviously works great. But adding more fields to the query results in longer loading times.
What is the strategy now regarding this, add more indexes, to cover all possible filter where queries? Or add one big index which covers all potential fields? Or is there another way to handle this?
Edit:
Here are my current indixes which I chose:
CREATE INDEX idx_vu_tid_dateDESC_amount ON tablename (vu, tid, date DESC, amount);

CREATE INDEX IDX_vu_tid_dateDESC_include ON tablename (vu, tid, date DESC)
INCLUDE (amount, status, "type", source, brand);

CREATE INDEX idx_type ON tablename (type);

CREATE INDEX idx_brand ON tablename (brand);

CREATE INDEX idx_source ON tablename (source);

CREATE INDEX idx_status ON tablename (status);

And here are the Query Plans of two different Queries, only difference are the vu and tids and yet it uses a different index. And it does not use multiple indixes, although available:
"Limit  (cost=0.57..489.21 rows=1 width=104) (actual time=6364.653..6364.656 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  ->  Index Scan using ""IDX_vu_tid_txdateDESC_amount"" on tablename (cost=0.57..489.21 rows=1 width=104) (actual time=6364.651..6364.651 rows=1 loops=1)"
"        Index Cond: (((vu)::text = '3xxxxx2'::text) AND ((tid)::text = ANY ('{3xxxx8,3xxxx7}'::text[])) AND (""date"" >= '2024-10-07 02:05:10.213+02'::timestamp with time zone) AND (""date"" <= '2024-12-08 11:05:10.213+01'::timestamp with time zone))"
"        Filter: (((""type"")::text = 'REVERSAL'::text) AND ((brand)::text = 'MxxxxxD'::text) AND ((status)::text = 'ok'::text))"
"        Rows Removed by Filter: 9596"
"Planning Time: 0.495 ms"
"Execution Time: 6364.932 ms"

"Limit  (cost=0.57..816.91 rows=1 width=104) (actual time=214.843..214.845 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  ->  Index Scan using idx_vu_tid_txdate_include on tablename (cost=0.57..816.91 rows=1 width=104) (actual time=214.841..214.841 rows=1 loops=1)"
"        Index Cond: (((vu)::text = '205188'::text) AND ((tid)::text = ANY ('{1xxxx2,1xxxx3}'::text[])) AND (""date"" >= '2024-09-07 02:05:10.213+02'::timestamp with time zone) AND (""date"" <= '2024-12-08 11:05:10.213+01'::timestamp with time zone))"
"        Filter: (((""type"")::text = 'REVERSAL'::text) AND ((brand)::text = 'MxxxxxD'::text) AND ((status)::text = 'ok'::text))"
"        Rows Removed by Filter: 10354"
"Planning Time: 1.810 ms"
"Execution Time: 5215.051 ms"


Check your query plans. That's where it starts.

I added the query plans and current avaiable indixes

It looks like you have a very slow system. It takes 6 seconds to get ~ 10k records and filter them. That should be a few milliseconds, not seconds. What kind of system is this or is it busy with other processes

If vu, tid and date are not queries with =, but with IN, or BETWEEN, the best option would be to have three b-tree indexes, one on each column. Other conditions that are added with AND will only reduce the number of rows, so if a query that filters only for vu, tid and date is fast, adding other conditions with AND shouldn't make the query slower.

I only saw a query use one index at a time. In this case would a query which has a where with vu, tid and date then use all 3 indexes one after another?

A query can use more than one index, but of course that is not always beneficial.

I added query plans and my current used indixes. But I dont quite understand why they are not used

I don't understand it either. Perhaps if you used EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS), it would become clearer.
